# HiberNate generated sequence value not in Sync with DB

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sequence

I am using Oracle as backend and when i try to insert any entry the sequence which hibernate is generating is of the order of "50010255" but in my db the current value of SEQ_AD_WORK sequence shows only "1000221" i am unable to figure out how that can happen.

following are my configurations

```
   <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.startup_check">false</prop>
            <!-- 
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            -->
        </props>
    </property>`

   @Id
@Column(name = "ITEM_ID", unique = true, nullable = false,  scale = 0)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_AD_WORK")
 @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_AD_WORK", sequenceName="SEQ_AD_WORK")
public Long getAdWorkItemId() {
    return this.adWorkItemId;
}
```

Comment: after enabling Debug i can see that hibernate is actually fetching the correct nextval from DB by after fetching it is converting into other value using rg.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator any idea why this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Dhirendra: try this:-

> @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_AD_WORK",sequenceName="SEQ_AD_WORK",,allocationSize=1)

SequenceHiLoGenerator is the default sequence generator for JPA and the default allocationSize value of 50,

Comment: thank's alot i got it working. just couldn't post the answer because i do not have enough reputation to post :)